# Multiplying a decimal value without using * operator in c++

Tags: c++

I was asked to create a calculator without using * in multiplication. The calculator must be able to add, subtract and multiply decimal value also.I'm having problems in the multiplication part. If I multiply a whole number I get the correct answer but if I multiply some decimal value, it outputs an incorrect answer. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, product = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, answer = 0, fres = 0, d = 0.01;

    std::cout << "\nEnter two values:\n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    while (a < 100) {
        product = product + num2;
        a++;
    }

    while (b < product) {
        fres = fres + num1;
        b++;
    }

    while (c < fres) {
        answer = answer + d;
        c++;
    }
    std::cout << answer;
}
```

Comment: You could remove almost all the code you show, keeping only the code inside the `case 3` to show us (and the definitions and initalizations of the used variables of course), truly making it a [mcve]. You could even hard-code input values for `num1` and `num2` and create a very simple `main` function that we could easily copy-paste and try ourselves.

Comment: I also recommend that you learn how to use a debugger to stepp through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. By debugging like that it should be possible that you figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: Lastly for an alternative for solving your problem: How would you do it using pen and paper? It's very straight-forward and relatively simple to translate the pen-and-paper way into code. I also recommend that you use *strings* to do it, since then it's must simpler to handle it digit by digit, and figure out the number of decimals after the decimal point for each number (and to pad the numbers so they have the same number of digits before and after the decimal point).

Comment: In binary floating point arithmetic, 100 * a * b * 0.01 is not necessarily equal to a * b.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is caused by the fact that repeated addition of a floating point type will likely cause the result to "go off": see for yourself by adding 0.1 ten times, for example. So you shouldn't necessarily return the value attained once the loop stops; perhaps the value immediately before that is closer to the result you want. If both arguments are non-integral then multiplication becomes a fair challenge, and the devil in me would look for an alternative that still satisfies the problem constraints:

Note that an alternative way to achieve multiplication which seems to me at least to satisfy the question constraints is to note that

```
a * b = std::exp(std::log(a) + std::log(b))
```

and

```
a / b = std::exp(std::log(a) - std::log(b))
```

A less facetious approach would be to use an algorithm based on exponentation by squaring, except that you add instead of multiply.

Comment: Very nice indeed! I could only think of some loops specifying a precision (3, 4, ... decimals).

Comment: The "algorithm based on exponentation by squaring" is known by various names, including [Ancient Egyptian multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication); it's simply binary long-multiplication.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Absolutely - that's very insightful. I've wiki'd the answer, do please feel free to contributed at your leisure.